# No me deja crear el servidor de postgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu

Acabo de instalar postgreSQL por medio de la teminal, luego intalé pgAdmin 4 para manejar las base de datos, cuando intento crear un servidor me aparece error
[image]

Comment: Creaste el usuario darksnow15, le asignaste una contraseña y después le diste los **GRANT** necesarios? Si fue así muéstranos tus querys editando tu pregunta por favor y reemplazando la imagen de tu error por texto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que PostgreSQL se instala con el usuario `postgres`, debes crear tu usuario para poder conectarte con tu gestor de base de datos:

```
sudo su -  #ingresas como usuario root
su postgres # pasas a ser el usuario postgres
createuser -RSP darksnow15 # creas el usuario, que no es super usuario y no puede crear roles y le te pedira contraseña
```